# AL crear una clase triangulo formada por 3 puntos de la clase Point y editar el Main me da error

Tags: java, netbeans, jpa

El ejecercicio consta de una clase Main.

```
package cognom_JPA_OBJECTDB;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Open a database connection, (create a new database if it doesn't exist yet):
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/db/p2.odb");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

 // Store 1000 Point objects in the database:
em.getTransaction().begin();
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
 Point p = new Point(i, i);
 em.persist(p);
 }

 em.getTransaction().commit();

 // Find the number of Point objects in the database:
 Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Point p");
 System.out.println("Total Points: " + q1.getSingleResult());

 // Find the average X value:
 Query q2 = em.createQuery("SELECT AVG(p.x) FROM Point p");
 System.out.println("Average X: " + q2.getSingleResult());

 // Retrieve all the Point objects from the database:
 TypedQuery<Point> query =
 em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Point p", Point.class);
 List<Point> results = query.getResultList();
 for (Point p : results) {
 System.out.println(p);
 }

 // Close the database connection:
 em.close();
 emf.close();
 }
}
```

Tenemos la clase Point:

```
package cognom_JPA_OBJECTDB;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
public class Point implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private long id;
 private int x;
 private int y;
 public Point() {}
 Point(int x, int y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 }
 public Long getId() {
 return id;
 }
 public int getX() {
 return x;
 }
 public int getY() {
 return y;
}
 @Override
 public String toString() {
 return String.format("(%d, %d)", this.x, this.y);
 }
}
```

Al ejecutar lo que tenemos de momento, sin editar nada, sale esto:

Total Points: 1000
Average X: 499.5
(0,0)
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
.
.
.
(998,998)
(999,999).

EL ejercicio lo que pide es Crear una nueva clase Triangulo formada por 3 puntos de la clase Point, y tendremos que editar la clase Main, para que en vez de guardar  mostrar 100 puntos, guarde y muestre 10 triángulos formados por 3 puntos cada uno.
SI cada punto tiene un Integer x e Y --> point(int x, int y);
Cada triangulo consta de 3 puntos --> Triangulo(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3);

Yo he editado y editado las siguientes clases.

mi classe Main.

```
package olle_jpa_objectdb;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Open a database connection, (create a new database if it doesn't exist yet):
EntityManagerFactory emf =
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/db/t2.odb");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

 // Store 1000 Point objects in the database:Generalitat de Catalunya
 em.getTransaction().begin();
 for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
 Triangle t = new Triangle(i, i, i);
 em.persist(t);
 }
 em.getTransaction().commit();

 // Find the number of Point objects in the database:
 Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(t) FROM Triangle t");
 System.out.println("Total Triangles: " + q1.getSingleResult());

 // Find the average X value:
 Query q2 = em.createQuery("SELECT AVG(t.x) FROM Triangle t");
 System.out.println("Average X: " + q2.getSingleResult());

 // Retrieve all the Point objects from the database:
 TypedQuery<Triangle> query =
 em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Triangle t", Triangle.class);
 List<Triangle> results = query.getResultList();
 for (Triangle t : results) {
 System.out.println(t);
 }

 // Close the database connection:
 em.close();
 emf.close();
 }
}
```

Mi clase triangulo

```
package olle_jpa_objectdb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

/**
 *
 * @author oscar
 */
@Entity
public class Triangle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id @GeneratedValue
    Point p1 = new Point();
    Point p2 = new Point();
    Point p3 = new Point();
    private long id;
    
@ManyToMany
    private List<Point> Point;

    public Triangle() {}
    Triangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
    this.p3 = p3;
    }

   
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public Point  getP1() {
        return p1;
    }
   public Point getP2() {
        return p2;
    }
   public Point getP3() {
        return p3;
    }
    
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d, %d, %d)", this.p1, this.p2, this.p3);
    }
}
```

Me gustaría saber si he de corregir algo en alguna clase, o si he de plantearlo de otra forma.